# How I alias a hostname without root access vis-a-vis gethostbyname?

Tags: networking, alias, non-root-user, host-name-resolution

I'm running a program which does (in its source code):

```
gethostbyname("whatever");
```

and I want it to use the local machine's address instead. I can't change the source. If I were root, it would be easy-peasy - I would just alias this name in /etc/hosts. But - is there something I can do as a *non_host* user for the same effect on my `gethostbyname()` call?

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` has:

```
hosts:      files nis dns myhostname
```

in case it matters.

Answer (score 2):

### Run it in a container

Using [podman](https://podman.io/) (or possibly rootless Docker) you could run your code inside a container in which you have set up an alias. E.g., I have the following code that calls `gethostbyname`:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    struct hostent *entry = gethostbyname(argv[i]);

    for (int j = 0; entry->h_addr_list[j] != NULL; j++) {
      printf("%s: %s\n", entry->h_name,
             inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)entry->h_addr_list[j]));
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If I compile this into the command `lookuphost` and then run `./lookuphost google.com`, I get:

```
$ ./lookuphost google.com
google.com: 142.251.32.110
```

If I want `google.com` to resolve to `1.2.3.4`, I can do something like this:

```
$ podman run -it --rm \
  --add-host google.com:1.2.3.4 \
  -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD fedora:37 \
  ./lookuphost google.com
google.com: 1.2.3.4
```

### Use function interposition

You can use [function interposition](https://www.jayconrod.com/posts/23/tutorial--function-interposition-in-linux) to wrap the `gethostbyname` call with your own code. For example, if I put the following in `gethostbyname.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name) {
  static struct hostent *(*real_gethostbyname)(const char *) = NULL;

  if (!real_gethostbyname) {
    real_gethostbyname = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "gethostbyname");
  }

  struct hostent *entry = real_gethostbyname(name);

  if (strcmp(name, "google.com") == 0) {
    struct in_addr inp;

    inet_aton("1.2.3.4", &inp);
    entry->h_addr_list[0] = (char *)&inp;
  }

  return entry;
}
```

And then build that into a shared library:

```
gcc -c -fPIC gethostbyname.c
gcc -shared -ldl -fPIC gethostbyname.o -o gethostbyname.so
```

I can `LD_PRELOAD` that and run `lookuphost` and get the expected answer:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./gethostbyname.so ./lookuphost google.com
google.com: 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use the [nss_wrapper](https://cwrap.org/nss_wrapper.html) preload library. It is similar to the suggestion by @larsks, but works at a slightly lower level (and provides emulation of passwd as well as hosts). Samba uses it for its testsuite.

  ```
  export LD_PRELOAD=libnss_wrapper.so
  export NSS_WRAPPER_HOSTS=/path/to/your/hosts
  ```
- Glibc *used to* have a specific feature for this – you could create a "host aliases" file via `$HOSTALIASES`, containing a list of `alias real.hostname.tld` pairs (i.e. an additional level of indirection, *not* pointing to IP addresses).

  ```
  $ export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts
  $ cat > $HOSTALIASES <<!
  whatever   real.example.net
  !
  ```

  However, I believe there were plans to remove this feature, and it no longer seems to work on my systems, at least not with `getent hosts`. If you're running a distro with an older Glibc, this may still work.

Comment: "I believe there were plans to remove this feature" it doesn't work for my either, but it seems to be in the man pages still.... any references?